# Open source solver for continuous-time non-linear stochastic DAEs (SDAEs)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, matlab, nonlinear-system, stochastic-pde

I am trying to solve a system of non-linear index-1 DAEs in which the derivatives of the state variables, $x(t)$ are corrupted by additive noise, $w(t)$ (whose co-variance matrix is known).

$\dot x(t) = f(x(t),t,u(t)) + w(t)$

Is there a known (open source) solver/library/package/toolbox in MATLAB/python/Julia (with or without adaptive time-stepping capability) that can solve the system?

Comment: Have you tried Modelica language? There are plenty of OpenSource implementations including OpenModelica and Jmodelica. They have a couple of Python wrappings too: PySimulator, OMPython...